# Laravel redirecting and stopping the app

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4, response

I'm trying to do a redirect from my service class. I don't want to return the url to the caller because it's not being accessed directly from controller and it should return other data in some cases.
However I found that i can do the redirect this way:

```
Redirect::away('http://someexternalurl.com')->send();
```

This seems to work fine - the user gets redirected to the url I entered. The problem is that in this case the app "lives on" so following commands get executed. That's not what I need.

If I `die();` immediately after that my session changes don't seem to be "saved".

Is there a way to make a redirect and stop the App immediately after that without simply "killing" it?

Basically is there a way to rewrite this code

```
Session::forget('myval');
Redirect::away('http://someexternalurl.com')->send();
mail('my@mail.com', 'Test', 'Still running');
```

So that myval would be gone from the session, the user would be redirected to the url and mail would not be sent (actually anything after the redirect shouldn't be executed)?

Thank you

Comment: use `Session::save()` before `die()`.

Comment: Does it mean that any changes I make to the Session instance aren't "stored" to the actual session until I or the app "commit" it with save method? What if there are more situations like this (some DB transactions, remote call libs etc.)? I can't make sure I "commit" all of them manually...

Comment: take it in a simple manner. if you call `die()`, whatever change you made in the session, it won't get reflected. you have to manually call the save method for this. rest (DB transactions) should work without any issue.

Comment: I'm sure this will work in this case. But maybe there's a way to tell the app to "take this response and shut down from here" so that all of these would be taken care of automatically...

Comment: when you say service class... are you meaning you are trying to redirect inside a service provider?

Comment: No, I mean that I use service provider to register some of my services. One of them is trying to do a redirect that I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to return on you Redirect?

`return Redirect::away('http://someexternalurl.com')->send();`

Comment: No, this only works inside routes or controller actions.

Comment: So where are you redirecting from? The only place you should be doing it is in a Controller or a Route

Comment: I wrote that it's done in one of my service classes. This is only used to redirect to external system in some cases so I can't be sure that a url to redirect to is always returned.

Comment: From an architecture point of view your "Service" shouldn't be responsible for interacting with the Framework or doing what you are trying to do.

Rather you should do something like have a function inside your Service class that returns a boolean for if the page should redirect that you call from a controller. And leave it out of your logic altogether.

Comment: I do understand that and usually it does work this way. In this case it will not necessarily have to redirect (depends on some conditions) and the controller itself doesn't even know about that dynamic url.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing - in your suggested code there's no need to call send(). And thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Well...after all I decided to rewrite some of my structures so the Response object ( return Redirect::away('theurl'); ) is now returned to the controller action in case a redirect is needed. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to throw an Exception and adapt the `render` method of the Exception Handler.

In Your Controller:

```
// app/Controllers/DashboardController.php

public function index()
{
    \App\Services\Test::test();

    return view('dashboard');
}
```

My example service :

```
// app/Services/Test.php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class Test {
    public static function test() {
        throw new \App\Exceptions\TestException('test');
    }
}
```

In your Exception Handler :

```
// app/Exceptions/Handler.php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof TestException) {
        return redirect(url('/?error=' . $exception->getMessage()));
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

My example Exception (you can name it whatever you want), it just needs to extend the default Exception.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

class TestException extends \Exception {

}
```

Comment: These seems like a nice solution. Note that you can also define the `render()` method directly on the custom exception rather than in the handler https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#renderable-exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution for Laravel 5.2. I reckon it would be work at all 5.*

```
abort(301, '', ['Location' => 'http://antondukhanin.ru']);
methodThatWouldntBeExecuted();
```

the function throws HttpException, so that will interrupt execution of any next commands